# When lid is closed ubuntu clicks on its own

Tags: suspend, laptop, power-management, touchscreen

- Close lid
- Go away for a few hours
- Come back to find a mess! Many many programs open.

Where do the clicks come from? (how can I find out?) and how do I fix things? Or at least how do I "workaround"?

Note that the laptop has a touch-screen which might be the cause.

Also note that I have "*when the lid is closed when plugged in* **do nothing**" which might also be related *(but I don't want it to suspend).*

Comment: Isn't it possible that touch screen is being touched by "something" when the lid is closed?

Comment: maybe but I don't have anything on the keyboard. (some protector or so..) But anyway it should detect that the lid is closed and disable all input from screen/keyboard/touchpad @ManishKumarBisht

Comment: @Frisky said "I am having the same issue. I do have a touch screen, but as Mina says, this should all be disabled when the laptop suspends. It appears that the laptop suspend is working, and having done several tests, if I open the laptop in a few to 5 minutes, all is as would be expected. But leave the laptop for a few hours, and I come back and I have tons of random open apps. It is like the laptop is being brought out of suspend. I have had to resort to shutting down the OS every time before closing my laptop." ...saved it because I was certain it'll be removed -_-